# Boost MPL push_back all elements in one vector into another

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

Just starting to look at boost MPL, say I have 2 vectors that I want to combine, is it possible with the boost MPL or do I need to write the code myself?

Say I have:

```
typedef vector<Class0, Class1, Class2, Class3> vec1;
typedef vector<Class4, Class5, Class6, Class7> vec2;
```

I did try `push_back` but I do not get the expected result:

```
typedef push_back<vec1, vec2>::type combinedVec;
```

What I end up with doing the above is a vector as follow:

```
vector<Class0, Class1, Class2, Class3, vector<Class4, Class5, Class6, Class7>>
```

What I want instead is:

```
vector<Class0, Class1, Class2, Class3, Class4, Class5, Class6, Class7>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: seems like that the types of the second vector aren't resolved. Looking into this, beside that I do not know whether someone would need this :D

Comment: @ArthurM. This question is actually a case of the XY problem, but with that said, even if it is, I would still personally like to know the solution to this specific issue.

Comment: I'm currently digging into this. I want to know the solution too :)

Comment: Can this be seen as bug or is the behaviour intended?